# Как нажать кнопку в JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нажать кнопку при помощи JMeter. 
Сейчас я ее нажимаю путем отправки POST запроса с параметрами. 
И нагрузочный тест кнопки не очень удобно проводить. Потому как одним из динамических параметров является цена и ID. 
Так вот как можно нажать кнопку?

```
oper:addBid
vehicleId:632881
amount:43000
bidType:2
badgeId:101
```

[image: Сама кнопка]

Comment: используйте другой инструмент.  JMeter для таких действий плохо подходит.

Comment: Какой инструмент вы можете порекомендовать, для тестирования кнопки?

Answer (score 1):

Jmetr не может взаимодействовать с элементами. Только отправка запросов